Example of a commutative semiring with cancel where $a*(b-c)= a*b - a*c$ fails
Let $(S,+,*,0)$ a commutative semiring  so $(S,+)$ is a commutative monoid
and $(S,*)$ is a commutative semigroup and $*$ distributes over $+$.
Let cancel $(-)$ be any operation such as:

It cancels addition:  $(a+b)-b = a$
It additively accumulates: $a - b - c = a - (b+c)$

Examples of such structures are commutative rings and $\mathbb{N}$ with monus (truncated addition).
Does $a * (b - c) = a*b - a*c$ always hold or is there a counterexample?

What means $a-b-c$? It could be $(a-b)-c$ or $a-(b-c)$. Please clarify.

Edit : corrected answer
The result is false. Let $S = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, let $+,*$ stand for the addition and multiplication on natural numbers. Let $\ominus$ be the weird operation defined by $a \ominus b = a - b$ if $a \geq b$ (i.e., normal substraction), but otherwise
$$a \ominus b = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $b+a$ is even} \\
1 & \text{if $b+a$ is odd }
\end{cases}$$
It is immediate that $\ominus$ cancels addition. To see that it additively accumulates, let $a,b,c$ be natural numbers, and consider $a \ominus b \ominus c$. There are three cases :
(i) $a \geq b+c$, (ii) $b < a < b+c$ and (iii) $a \leq b$.
$\bullet$ (i) In the first case, we have $a \ominus b \ominus c = (a - b) \ominus c = a - b - c = a - (b + c) = a \ominus (b + c)$.
$\bullet$ (ii) In the second case, $a\ominus b \ominus c = (a-b) \ominus c$ which is $a+b+c \text{ mod } 2$, the same as $a \ominus (b+c)$.
$\bullet$ (iii) In the third case, on the one hand, if $a+b$ is even, then $a \ominus b \ominus c = 0 \ominus c$ which is $c \text{ mod } 2 = a + b + c \text{ mod } 2$. On the other hand, if $a+b$ is odd then $a\ominus b \ominus c$ is $1 \ominus c$ which is $c + 1 \text{ mod } 2 = a + b + c \text{ mod } 2$ again. This is indeed $a \ominus (b +c)$.
Now, notice that
$$2 * (1 \ominus 2) = 2 * 1 = 2 \quad \text{but} \quad  2* 1 \ominus 2 * 2 = 2 \ominus 4 = 0 \ominus 2 = 0 $$

Oh wait there is an issue with $b = b - c + c$. I can say that $b = (b + c) - c$ but we don't assume that $-$ commutes with $+$...

5 !=  (5 - 6) +6  (for example in N, where 5 - 6 = 0)

@Slei. I updated the answer. I think the result is false, provided I did not miss something else.

I tried your counter-example in Isabelle, you didn't miss anything. Good find! Thanks.

I'd be interested to see the Isabelle verification!
